# How to set a trigger for multiple label each one based on a button focused in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to raise a trigger on Label each time a Textbox related to it get focused. I did this but I have many label in many form. Is there any way to that in resources level, I will be appreciated for any help and thanks. I figured out to use Tag to pass the Textbox name to the trigger but I don't know how to do that!

```
<Label Grid.Column="0"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Content="{StaticResource CIN}"
       Tag="">
       <Label.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Label">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TxCIN, Path=IsFocused}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                      </DataTrigger>
                 </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
       </Label.Style>
</Label>
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" 
         Grid.Row="0" 
         Name="TxCIN"/>
```

Comment: Couldn't you simply move your Label's style to the App.Xaml `staticResources` and give it an x:key?

Comment: And what about the Textbox that should refer to it?

Comment: Are you saying that the `TextBox` is defined in a `Window`, and the labels are located in different windows ?

Comment: No both off theme in same windows but I have many label and many Textbox and every time a Textbox get focused a label font change for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample for you:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="LabelStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=Children[1].IsFocused}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Content="First Name:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Content="Last Name:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
        <Label Content="Address:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
        <Label Content="Zip Code:" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox Width="150"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

If you see then a common style is applied to all the labels. My ancestor is the StackPanel and the TextBox is the second sibling hence Path=Children[1].IsFocused. Please change the AncestorType and the Children's index as per your xaml.